# c# compact framework 3.5 importing multiple certificates

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I would like to use C# Compact Framework (CF) 3.5 to import multiple X509Certificates. The existing library System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates supports single certificate import. Is there a way to import multiple certificates using using C# Compact Framework? Has anybody implemented this previously in a way that I can reference?

Newer versions of C# support X509CertificatesCollection which is not available in the CF that I am using.

I have pre-defined dependencies on an existing platform that require me to use

- c#
- Compact Framework 3.5
- Windows CE

I have implemented this and tried to reverse engineer the X509CertificateCollection.

---

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;


class MyProgram
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileName = "c:\\cert\\file_0.cer";
        string password = "Labuser1";
        bool result  = isSingleCertificate(fileName, password);
        ParseMultipleCertificates(fileName, password);
    }

    static bool isSingleCertificate(string path, string password)
    {
        bool isSingle; // = true;
        X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        // X509CertificateCollection collection = new X509CertificateCollection();
        collection.Import(path, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        isSingle = (collection.Count == 1) ? true : false;
        return isSingle;
    }

    static List<string> ParseMultipleCertificates(string path, string password)
    {
        X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        // X509CertificateCollection collection = new X509CertificateCollection();

        collection.Import(path, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        int index = 0;
        List<string> filePathList = new List<string>();

         int inc = 0;

        foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in collection)
        {
            ++inc;
            string filename = "c:\\cert\\temp\\file_" + inc.ToString() + ".cer"; // = GetTempFilePathWithExtension(".cer");
            filePathList.Add(filename);
            byte[] myArray = new byte[10000];
            if (password.Length > 0) myArray = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert, password);
            else cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert);

            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    fileStream.WriteByte(myArray[i]);
                }

                fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                fileStream.Close();
            }
        }
        return filePathList;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see an actual question here, but perhaps I missed it...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @bartonjs Thank you for asking for clarification. I have added the request above to see if anybody had implemented multiple certificate import via C# Compact Framework 3.5